# Failed to load resource ...rxjs-extensions.js

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to repeat

[angular2 official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)

I have added

```
import './rxjs-extensions';
```

to the `AppModule`

now it looks like this:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import './rxjs-extensions';

import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }     from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }         from './hero.service';
import {DashBoardComponent} from "./dashboard.component";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";
import {InMemoryWebApiModule} from "angular-in-memory-web-api";
import {InMemoryDataService} from "./in-memory-data.service";
import {HeroSearchComponent} from "./hero-search.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpModule,
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroDetailComponent,
        HeroesComponent,
        DashBoardComponent,
        HeroSearchComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        HeroService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

When I start application I see error in browser console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:229 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/rxjs-extensions.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/rxjs-extensions.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:851:29) [<root>]
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:332:33) [<root>]
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/rxjs-extensions.js as "./rxjs-extensions" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:851:29) [<root>]
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:332:33) [<root>]
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/rxjs-extensions.js as "./rxjs-extensions" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

What did I miss?

Comment: did you add the actual `app/rxjs-extensions.ts` **file** from [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html#!#import-rxjs-operators) step?

Comment: @benny_boe is the man ! This is most probably the reason.

Comment: @benny_boe I didn't catch that I need to create new file at this step.THX!

Comment: @gstackoverflow Glad it worked out & happy coding ;-)